# How Azure Devops self-hosted agent get access to Azure Cloud resources?

Tags: azure

When Azure Devops pipeline runs, I assume Azure Devops self-hosted agent get access to Azure cloud through "Service Connections" configured on Azure Devops GUI for specific Azure cloud subscription. I would like to know how service connection works with the self-hosted agent VM. Like What configuration in the self-hosted agent VM I can check for service connection info? To be more specific, as a first step, Azure pipeline codes are downloaded in self-hosted agent when pipeline runs. Then agent runs the code (supported by related packages like powershell) for resource deployment in Azure cloud. How "service connection" is used to establish connection between the agent and azure cloud before running the deployment code?

Answer (score 0):

The service connection is obtained and used by the task that needs to connect to Azure. For example, the Azure CLI task will use the service connection details to perform the "az login" command at the start of the task.